# Pandas DataFrame and DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to group rows by time and I tried the following approach

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["2001-01-01 10:20:30,000", 
                            "2001-01-01 10:20:31,000",
                            "2001-01-02 5:00:00,000"],
                    'val': [1, 2, 3]})

t = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.time)
df = df.groupby([t.day, t.hour, t.minute]).count()
```

The resulting dataframe is

```
                   time val
    time time time      
       1   10   20    2   2
       2    5    0    1   1
```

The output I expect (or something similar):

```
           time   count             
     1  1-10-20       2
     2    2-5-0       1
```

The plot I want: `X`-axis for minutes, `Y`-axis for `count`, ticks by day + hour (coarser than just minutes).

**Questions:**

1) Why the index consist of 3 `time` columns and how can I have the index with just a single column with elements like `1-10-20` and `2-5-0`?

2) What is the best practice to have only one column with the results of `count()` instead of two columns `time` and `val`?

2) How can I plot this data (grouped by days/hours/minutes) with ticks in days and hours?

Comment: Given the example you provide what is the output you expect?

Comment: Can you clarify about the plot you want? The other two questions are easier

Comment: @user3483203 I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, it's because you're grouping by three separate series.  If you really want them combined, group by a `strftime`:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)

df.groupby([df.time.dt.strftime('%d-%H-%M')]).val.count()
```

```
time
01-10-20    2
02-05-00    1
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

The above also answers your second question.  Instead of counting the DataFrame, count a single series, your `val` series.

---

Finally, to plot, you can use the builtin `plot` functionality of `pandas`.  I am creating a more complex example to demonstrate the ticks you want:

```
r = pd.date_range(start='2001-01-01', freq='5T', periods=100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':r, 'val': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100)})

out = df.groupby([df.time.dt.strftime('%d-%H-%M')]).val.count().reset_index()

ax = out.assign(label=out.time.str[:5]).plot(x='label', y='val', kind='bar')

seen_ticks = set()

for idx, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if label.get_text() in seen_ticks:
        label.set_visible(False)
    else:
        seen_ticks.add(label.get_text())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This will show only unique x-ticks for minute/hour

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Can you please clarify how I can have bins for day/hour/minute, but ticks only for day/hour (coarser) because there are quite a lot of bins.

Comment: I don't know what that means unfortunately.  If you can show an example plot that demonstrates the concept I can update the answer

Comment: For each hour there are 60 dots and there are multiple hours. I want all the data points (per each minute) to be present on the graph but the ticks on X-axis should only be for days/hours, not minutes. So there are much less ticks than data points.

Comment: Something like this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/_images/series_plot_basic.png but with ticks for days/hours.

Comment: @Konstantin demonstrated a way to show less x-ticks

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` to create a dataframe from a dictionary. (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

2) This question isn't entirely clear, but I think what you want is

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
```

and then apply your `count()` aggregation.

3) This question isn't clear to me.